# Is it safe to turn off kernel panic in Android?

Tags: root-access, kernel, overheating, cpu, overclocking

So I'm using a custom kernel that overclocked my CPU and GPU. I turned down the frequency to stock but the big cpu freq can't be set(restore itself to default after some time), causing my phone to heat up if I'm having heavy workload/game. When my phone is really hot, kernel panic comes in and reboot my phone, I hate it when it happen while I'm gaming.

I looked up why it reboot and the cause is kernel panic. So I searched how to disable kernel panic and so I did.

My phone doesn't reboot anymore. But I'm thinking is it okay to disable it? I can't use another kernel cause it the only one kernel that support custom rom and having hotplug (really helpful at saving battery and less cpu heat). And I don't know how to recompile a kernel.

My tweaks.sh

```
sysctl -w kernel.panic=0
sysctl -w kernel.panic_on_oops=0
sysctl -w kernel.softlockup_panic=0
```

Comment: Forcing operating system to continue execution when it thinks it should abort is never safe. In extreme cases this may damage the hardware, as you pointed out that panic occurs due to overheating. Better avoid. Even better is to never let the temperature raise above safe threshold. Kernel documentation: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt